# Initializing a C++11 string with {}

Tags: string, c++11

What is the difference between initializing a string with:

```
std::string testString = "Test";
```

and

```
std::string testString{"Test"};
```

Is this only syntactic sugar thing or there actually are some performance related differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `{}` initialization syntax is known as the uniform initialization syntax, it has a few key differences, but in your code as is they both do the same thing - construct a `std::string` object from the string literal `"Test"`

Initializing an object with an assignment is essentially the same as putting the right hand side in parentheses and constructing the object.  For example the below two are the same

```
T obj = a;
T obj(a);
```

So you should be asking yourself, what is the difference between constructing a string object the following two ways

```
std::string{"Test"};
std::string("Test");
```

And the answer is that both the constructions above are the same and call the same constructor for `std::string`

---

For more on uniform initialization see https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133688/is-c11-uniform-initialization-a-replacement-for-the-old-style-syntax

Comment: I'm still confused. Is constructor and copy constructor essentially the same ? How does uniform initialization and initiallizer list work? How's the const char* object ended up with?

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in this particular case. But try

```
std::string s1(1, '0'); // calls string(size_type , char )
std::string s2{1, '0'}; // calls string(std::initializer_list<char> )

assert(s1.length() == 1 && s1[0] == '0');
assert(s2.length() == 2 && s2[0] == '\x1');
```

or with `std::vector`

```
std::vector<int> v1(1); // calls vector(size_type )
std::vector<int> v2{1}; // calls vector(std::initializer_list<int> )

assert(v1.size() == 1 && v1[0] == 0);
assert(v2.size() == 1 && v2[0] == 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no difference between them.

First declaration is preferred in most projects due to the syntax highlighting.

Comment: What sort of syntax highlighting is missing in the second one?

Comment: @Curious aren't you ;) I think it's more readable. I don't see any missing syntax highlighting either.

Comment: There is nothing  missing @Curious. I just want to say first one is more readable.

Comment: your opinion on which is more readable isn't really relevant.  Saying that it's preferred in most projects is not even clear that it's your opinion.

Comment: First declaration is preferred, because it is more readable. That is not my opinion. All my friends use first declaration on their projects. Is it relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I found a clear answer in Herb Sutter

https://herbsutter.com/2013/05/09/gotw-1-solution/